# Directive: ngModel not change ng-hide

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I started build a directive calendar and I have a problem:

I'm putting dynamic tables and want to filter by a ngModel that is parent controller, but I can not take the change of ngModel using dynamic tables and attr.

Here is the code:

HTML

```
<li class="checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="confirm.is_true" checked class="checked-blue">
   <label>Confirm</label>
</li>
```

JS

```
function createBar(kind) {
    var _span = document.createElement("div");
    switch(kind){
      case "initial":
        var _img = document.createElement("img");
        var _text = document.createTextNode("Test");
        _img.src = "/uploads/photo/27/sq135_DSC_0011.JPG";
        _span.appendChild(_img);
        _span.appendChild(_text);
        _span.className = "bar-init";
        _span.setAttribute("ng-hide", "confirm.is_true");
        break;
      case "middle":
        _span.className = "bar-middle";
        break;
      case "end":
        _span.className = "bar-end";
        break;
    }
    return _span;
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: Where is the directive code? And why do you need to add elements dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, I think that angular is not aware of the fact that you are creating this element. You should definitely have a look into `$compile` method. Instead of using `document.createElement` use `angular.element`. After creating desired element, use `$compile(_span)($scope)`.